# Do android support multiple languages?

Tags: android, multilingual

If i run my android application with a htc magic with locale English, I find my application running properly and if i try to run it on Motorola droid with locale korean, My application(apk) is not even installing on the device. Does android support different language? Is it is because of different language OS versions?

Comment: Look for [localization!](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Multilanguage support is easy done for android. Create a new `values` directory for the language with the suffix of the language code. For german: `values-de` or french: `values-fr` than copy your strings.xml into that and translate each entry. Thats all you need.

Comment: it's called `strings.xml` not `string.xml`. Though in your code later you will refer to it as `R.string.blah`.

Comment: @WarrenFaith But all the data Display from webservice then how to manage?how to handle every resources file?

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh there are different ways: you could return the @string/key so that your device/app translates or you could just translate on the webservice. In that case you need to send the device language to the service as well.

Comment: @WarrenFaith so any translate app require in device?

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh I am not sure if I understand you... what do you mean by "translate app"?

Comment: @WarrenFaith if are u free then join this chat room.http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat i talk every thing.my main answer is how to manage web response with different country language?

Answer (score 4):

There is the table of values to add in yours values folder.
[iso639-2](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)

ex: if you like translate your app to spanish you must create a new folder in
your res folder called, values-es, and copy inside string.xml file tranlated.