# Android : How can i make my application multilingual?

Tags: java, android, multilingual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a multilingual android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259128/how-can-i-create-a-multilingual-android-application)

I am creating application and i am in the testing phase, but i want to make my application multilingual.

How can i make it multilingual ?
What is the best way to make it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing that you need to do is to create new folders in your `res` folder.

Example : If you need to add support to spanish and italian you need to do it like this :

1. res folder

   1.1 values

   1.2 values-es // spanish

   1.3 values-it  // italian

And after that you need to create `string.xml` files in `values-es` and `values-it`. And in all files you just need to create all string which you want to use like this :

```xml
<string name="title">Title</string>  // in values folder
<string name="title">Title in Spanish</string>  // in values-es folder
and etc.
```

And after that you can use these string as :

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
text.setText(getString(R.string.title));
```

And this should work.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this tutorial about localizing applications: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html.

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Numerous examples are available that can help you create multilingual app in android.

Have a look on these articles :

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html

http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/

this will help you to create multilingual app in android.