# Regarding Multiple Language Application for Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make small app for android. My idea for app is that user can change the language whichever they want ...etc french , german,chinese , english etc...
how to force the locale language in my app or how to get access to the language used by user on  their device and with respect to that I can change my application language.

THank you,

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259128/how-can-i-create-a-multilingual-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you may need to make use of Localization.

Please go through the following example available at the developer site.

May be this can solve your issue.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html