# Dynamically Assigning string values across views in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and need help on this. I have two views
VIEW 1 - comprises of a spinner that species the user select a preferred language to send an SMS, 
VIEW 2 - Comprises of textviews,editText(containing hints) and buttons.

I'd like to have the user select a preferred language in VIEW 1 and on doing that,the hints are specified using the language selected. Say for example I select english, the text and hints in VIEW 2 should be english. And if I select french they should be in french.

Ps, How could I do this. I am clueless on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `onItemSelectedListener` read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).

[here is another example of it in use.](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517)

Since you want to use multiple languages read up on Android Resources and Localization. 
Here is a [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259128/how-can-i-create-a-multilingual-android-application) with some more information on that.