# Choose language android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an app that supports multiple languages, where you choose your language at the beginning.
When the app starts I would like to have a fragment that lets you choose a language. One button per language.
After that i would like to open my main_Activity that has two fragments in it, but i would like it to use the correct string-??.xml
How can i do that?

fragment_language

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.user1.lotus.LanguagesFragment"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id = "@+id/languages">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/english"
                    android:layout_column="0"

                    android:tint="#33B5E5"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="0.50"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="0.33"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:text="@string/english"
                    android:singleLine="false" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/french"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:tint="#c8b3ca"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="0.50"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="0.33"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/french" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/greek"
                    android:layout_column="0"


                    android:tint="#b6ff7e"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="0.50"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="0.33"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:text="@string/greek" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/spanish"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:tint="#f1c40f"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="0.50"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="0.33"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:text="@string/spanish" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/korean"
                    android:layout_column="0"


                    android:tint="#ff2646"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="0.50"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="0.33"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:text="@string/korean" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/arabic"
                    android:layout_column="1"

                    android:tint="#ffa500"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="0.50"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="0.33"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.50"
                    android:text="@string/arabic" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/voyage">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/side_bar"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.user1.lotus.SideBarFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For that you need to make different `values` folder. Suppose if you want to implement app for `English` and `Arabic` then the folders will be `values-en` and `values-ar`. And your `strings.xml` files both have a same string name

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a multilingual android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259128/how-can-i-create-a-multilingual-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void setUserLanguage(final String lng) {
    final Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
    setUserLanguage(locale);
}
public static void setUserLanguage(final Locale locale) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    final Resources res = getAppContext().getResources();
    final Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    //res.updateConfiguration(config, null);
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: Doesnt this take the language of the device? i want to choose with the buttons...

Comment: Just pass corresponding `Locale` or ISO language string like `en` ot `it` to methods and it will switch your app to use corresponding `strings.xml`.