# Android list of language identifiers for values

Tags: android

I want to implement multilanguage in my app. I've read the following documentation and it was very intresting ([Do android support multiple languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626976/do-android-support-multiple-languages)).

I understand how it works, but is there a list of identifiers available?

For example, if I want to implement the language Dutch, is it enough to implement the first two letters of the language (in this case 'ne') or not?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually those are not the first two letters of the language, but the  [ISO 639-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)  language code. E.g. 'de' for German, 'fr' for French and 'nl' for Dutch.
See the docs on [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

here are the language codes http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

You want to use the iso 639-1 code

e.g. for Spanish create a values folder named values-es

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers are not correct. Android locales are build on ISO 639-1 but offer more specific codes. For example, Brazil is not listed in ISO 639-1, but Android allows for a `values-pt-rBR` folder to target Brazil only.

See https://github.com/championswimmer/android-locales for all available locales