# How can I create a multilingual android application for right to left languages?

Tags: android, localization, multilingual, bidirectional

I have read [How can I create a multilingual android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4259128/779408) and [Do android support multiple languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3626976/779408) and I know about creating an android application with multiple languages. But my problem is about showing right-to-left and left-to-right texts for different languages.

For example in English a `TextView` as label should be on the left side of `EditText` and in Persian, `TextView` should be on the right side of `EditText`.

[image]
[image]

How can I support right to left languages and UIs in my user interface?

Should I design different layouts for right to left languages? How can I specify a folder in layouts for RTL? something like `layout-rtl`? Or how can I determine the language is right to left?

Is there any easier way?

Comment: hope this can help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch                   and slow this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official support was introduced in Android 4.2, see [RTL Layout Support](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL). You can query whether it is being used through [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_LAYOUTDIR_RTL).

You can either try and use the same layout in all cases, or specify a specific layout in 'layout-ldrtl'.

As per your example, if you're using the [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) you need to use the [android:layout_alignParentStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_START) attribute, rather than the [android:layout_alignParentLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT) to shift your label from left to right automatically.

Comment: Make sure you also add android:supportsRtl="true" inside application tag in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of words that are not translatable, so that you know that calling those resources it will get always the same languages.
For example:

```
<string name="english">English</string>
<string name="english_fixed" translatable="false">English </string>
```

In this case the reference to `R.string.english_fixed` will always display the same string while `R.string.english` will translate the word.
Then, you can use the two different resources in two different TextViews, on the left and on the right.

Did I understand the question?