# android - displaying non supporting languages

Tags: android, multilingual

In my android app I have to use both Sinhala and English languages to be chosen for the user. In this case android not supporting Sinhala. Can i use Unicode or another font in representing Sinhala. how can I map Sinhala to Strings folder.

Comment: May this url might help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626976/do-android-support-multiple-languages]